# Looking for some basic examples of finite subcovers of various compact topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm not sure exactly what to put here, because my question isn't about a particular space. I'm not really sure if I fully understand the concept of compactness, and I was hoping someone might know an example that would help me with this.

Here's my basic understanding so I can verify I have the right idea. Many (or all?) topological spaces have an infinite number of open coverings we could consider. We say our topological space is compact if every single one of these open coverings has a finite refinement. In that sense, for a given open covering we require that each open set in that covering has a finite refinement. I'm still unsure what that last part means, because the definition as I understand it seems extremely lax. For a given open set, how is the open set itself not a "finite subcover"?

Comment: A more common definition uses the notion of a subcover rather than a refinement (these are not the same things!). If $\mathcal{U}$ is a covering of $X$, then a *subcovering* is a subfamily $\mathcal{U}'\subset\mathcal{U}$ such that $X=\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}'}U$. Then $X$ is *compact* if and only if each open covering of it has a finite subcovering if and only if each open covering of it has a finite refinement. You might find the subcovering definition easier to get the hang of: the only thing that changes is that the collection of open sets 'gets smaller'. The sets themselves do not change.

Comment: For example, $\{[0,1/n)|n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{(1/n,1]|n\in\mathbb N\}$ is an open cover of $[0,1]$, and $\{[0,1),(0,1]\}$ is a finite subcover

Comment: On the other hand, $\{(1/n,1-1/n)|n\in\Bbb N\}$ is an open cover of $(0,1)$ that has no finite subcover

Answer (score 1):

$\{(1/n,1-1/n)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ is an open cover of $(0,1)$ --

a collection of open sets whose union contains $(0,1)$.

However, there is no finite subcover; that is, you cannot select finitely many open sets

in this particular collection that are an open cover of $(0,1)$.  Therefore, $(0,1)$ is not compact.

On the other hand, $[0,1]$ is compact, so any open cover of $[0,1]$ has a finite subcover.

For example, the open cover $\{[0,1/n)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{(1/n,1]\mid n\in \mathbb  N\}$ of $[0,1]$

has $\{[0,1),(0,1]\}$ as a finite subcover.